# Is it possible to run Raspberry Pi's HDMI output to a USB port on another computer to see the video?

Tags: hdmi

I want to use a Raspberry Pi, along with an external USB hard drive, as a miniature SSH server, but I don't have a monitor or TV to use with it. It isn't worth it to buy a monitor/TV for the set up, since once I have the SSH set up I won't need any output (I could do the work remotely) but I don't know of any other way to see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the system running to configure sshd, and *I think* the stock raspbian (and probably other distros) will start the server by default.  They certainly will have it pre-installed.  So you can, **for certain**, set this up without the pi, meaning you don't have to worry about the monitor.

Mount the SD card on your computer and configure /etc/ssh/sshd_config to allow root login, add your public key to $HOME, etc.  That's the easy part, presuming you know how to configure sshd.

Next, check that sshd is actually set to start in /etc/rc2.d (runlevel 2 seems to be the default on raspbian, although it seems like 3 to me, but those directories are more or less the same).  If you see `@S03ssh` or something in there, you are good to go.  If not, you can just add such a symlink (the target is `/etc/init.d/ssh`), which will work although you may want to do a more proper debian services thing once the system is running.

```
ln -s ../init.d/ssh S03ssh
```

Put the SD card and an ethernet cable from your LAN into the pi, then plug in the pi power.  Wait a minute or two and ssh in.  If you need wifi, you'll have to do more configuration on the card first, so hopefully you have a cable.

If you don't get some part of this, ask specifically and I can explain in more detail.

Comment: I think that all makes sense. Since I'm planning to run the [Raspbian “wheezy”](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) OS, i.e. a Debian-based distro, what should I do to configure a "more proper debian services thing once the system is running" ?

Also, just to clarify completely, the symlink command you're running is `ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc2.d/S03ssh`, right?

Comment: WRT debian services, they have a README in `/etc/init.d`.  The proper way to enable a boot service on debian is `update-rc.d ssh enable`, but you need the system running.  WRT to the symlink: yes, that would be it, except if you are doing this with the SD card mounted and you use the full path `/etc/init.d/ssh` it refers to your system, not `/mnt/sdcard`.  That is actually okay, since it will be correct when you boot.  Using the relative path is just less confusing.  Whatever you do, *do not* use the full path `/mnt/sdcard/etc/init.d/ssh` when defining the link!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**, at least not in the way you're thinking of.

It's true that one could use an HDMI capture card ([Amazon has several](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&keywords=hdmi%20capture%20card&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ahdmi%20capture%20card)) to capture the Pi's output and display it on the computer, but this route is likely more expensive than just buying a cheap monitor or using a monitor that you already have.

If the problem is that the monitors you have don't have HDMI, then you could use an HDMI-to-DVI cable (like [this one](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/24-11050)) to hook up the Pi.